# How does windows spot light decides what "I like"?

Tags: windows-10, windows-spotlight

My windows 10 login screen uses "windows spot light".

For some strange reason, windows thinks I like winter and keeps showing me "beautiful" photos of cold dark winter scenaries, which to me is like showing pictures of hell. Meanwhile my colleague gets pictures of sunny beaches and waves.

I' ve downvoted the pics every time and still new awful winter landscapes keep appearing. :(

How can I get the sunny beaches and summer scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we may can’t set what we like in windows spotlight.
If you still want to use this function, you can try to reset the windows spotlight.  Maybe you will see the lock screen you like next time.
The following article is about how to reset windows spotlight:
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-fix-windows-spotlight-stuck-same-image-windows-10

If you just want to see beach and summer scenarios, you can go to set lock screen.
Settings-->Personalization-->Lock screen

[image]